# Why can I delete a 755 file when I'm not the owner?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I have this file:

```
$ ls -l  store.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root apache    117 Feb  5  2016 store.sh

$ id
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)
```

I think that I haven't the permission to edit this file but was possible delete and replace the file. How can it be? Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You don't need write permissions on a file to delete or move (rename) it. You need write permissions on the directory *containing* the file, because *deleting or renaming are not operations on the file, but operations on the directory's list of files*. So in this case the directory of this file probably has write access for the `apache` user or the `apache` group.

Comment: Thx a lot, this is clear and make sense. I have write permission on that folder. Thank you very much

Comment: This does not make sense to me... if you can delete the file, then create a different file with the same name, then effectively you edited the file!

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi but you actually haven't. In particular if the same file was also linked under a different name, possibly in a different directory, it is still there unchanged. Or if it was opened by some process, the process still accesses that file, not the new one you created.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: Files don't have names: *directory entries* have names. You can change which file a directory entry points to, but that doesn't change the file at all, and it doesn't affect any other pointers to that file (e.g. other links to the file or programs that have it open).

Comment: That's scary and very broken.

Comment: @RonJohn Not really. The actual contents of the file are on the disk and you can't edit that. The name you are editing just points to that file. It's essentially just a hard link that you're editing.

Comment: @RonJohn: absolutely not. You should have the rights on the directory that you need to have, no more, no less. Admins will need to monitor and change the rights on the directories to really match the needs and the security they want. That the OP could delete a file he couldn't edit is not broken, but it may point out that the rights on his server (on that particular tree branch) may not really be well set up.

Comment: @OlivierDulac I can easily think of scenarios where an end-user should be able to create/edit/remove some files in a directory, but not others.

Comment: @RonJohn For those scenarios give those files and the user a specific groups and give that group the w right on the directory. And there is even possibilities to add acls for further specific needs. And also sticky bits help (see /tmp where every users can create and edit files but can't remove other people's files)

Comment: @RonJohn That's when it turns out you finally need to read up on SELinux security contexts/policies.

Comment: @OlivierDulac the lack of multiple groups per directory, and need for ACLs shows that the Unix file protection scheme *is* broken.

Comment: @Ron it's not *broken*, it's limited.  There are a certain set of use cases that are served very well by POSIX permission schemes, and some use cases which need ACLs on top of those, and some which can't be done with either, so you need to rework the directory structure and ownerships around those limitations. It's a reasonable compromise between of simplicity of implementation and simplicity of use.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a file doesn't modify the file in question rather it modifies the  parent directory as it removes the file from directory listing. This also means that you  have full permissions to the parent directory of the file